# pyspark schema validation for csv

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, union

I have raw data in a pyspark dataframe df1 (read from a csv file). When I try to append another csv (will be read in another pyspark dataframe df2), Is there an elegant way of checking or validating the schema of both before I  "union" both the dataframe? Thanks.

Comment: Both dataframe have the same schema ? do you already know the schema ?

Comment: I know the schema of df1. I want to check if df2's schema is same as df1 before I "union" both the dataframe. Or I am trying to say that my csv headers for csv are different (i.e) df2. Basically I want to check if the header names for df1 and df2 are same before I union both. Thanks.

Comment: just the header ? `assert df1.columns == df2.columns`. But if you want to union by names, you have directly a method for that : [`df1.unionByName(df2)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what kind of validation are you looking for ?

1. Matching columns names
   if you just want to know that the same columns are present or not , you can use

   `df1.select(df2.columns)`
2. I think if you are trying to do a union it is important that you check for data types and whether the column is nullable or not for that you can use :

   `df1.schema==df2.schema`

you can put them as assert or if conditions as per your use case .